# Check_sudoku in Python

Tags: python, beginner, sudoku

I have just started to learn programming with Python. I have been going through several online classes for the last month or two. Please bear with me if my questions are noobish.

One of the classes I am taking asked us to solve this problem.

```
# Define a procedure, check_sudoku,
# that takes as input a square list
# of lists representing an n x n
# sudoku puzzle solution and returns the boolean
# True if the input is a valid
# sudoku square and returns the boolean False
# otherwise.

# A valid sudoku square satisfies these
# two properties:

#   1. Each column of the square contains
#       each of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.


#   2. Each row of the square contains each
#       of the whole numbers from 1 to n exactly once.

# You may assume the the input is square and contains at
# least one row and column.
```

After a while of trying to come up with the best code I can, this is what I ended up with.

```
def check_sudoku(sudlist):
    x = range(1, len(sudlist)+1) # makes a list of each number to be found
    rows = [[row[i] for row in sudlist] for i in range(len(sudlist))] # assigns all the rows to a flat list
    z = range(len(sudlist))
    for num in x:
        for pos in z:
            if num not in sudlist[pos] or num not in rows[pos]:
                return False
    return True
```

This code does work and passed all checks the class asked for.  I just wonder what problems could the code have or how would you improve it?

I am just trying to improve by getting input from others.  I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The problem seems poorly stated. A Sudoku grid has *three* types of constraint: rows, columns, and *blocks*. A grid that only has row and column constraints is known as a [Latin square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square).

Answer (score 8):

I would use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to do the checks, and you can build the columns using some [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) magic:

```
def check_sudoku(sudlist) :
    numbers = set(range(1, len(sudlist) + 1))
    if (any(set(row) != numbers for row in sudlist) or
        any(set(col) != numbers for col in zip(*sudlist))) :
        return False
    return True
```

I have tested it with the following samples:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [2, 3, 5, 1, 4],
     [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
     [4, 1, 2, 5, 3],
     [5, 4, 1, 3, 2]] # latin square

b = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [2, 3, 5, 1, 4],
     [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
     [4, 1, 2, 5, 3],
     [3, 4, 1, 5, 2]] # 1st and 4th elements of last row interchanged

c = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [2, 4, 5, 1, 4],
     [3, 5, 4, 2, 1],
     [4, 1, 2, 5, 3],
     [5, 3, 1, 3, 2]] #1st and 5th elements of second column intechanged


>>> check_sudoku(a)
True
>>> check_sudoku(b)
False
>>> check_sudoku(c)
False
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def check_sudoku(sudlist):
    x = range(1, len(sudlist)+1) # makes a list of each number to be found'
```

Avoid storing things in single-letter variable names. It just makes it hearder to folllow your code

```
    rows = [[row[i] for row in sudlist] for i in range(len(sudlist))] # assigns all the rows to a flat list
```

You could actually do `rows = zip(*sudlist)` which will do the same thing. Admittedly, if you've not seen the trick before its non-obvious.

```
    z = range(len(sudlist))
    for num in x:
```

There's not really any reason to store the list in x, and then iterate over it later. Just combine the lines.

```
        for pos in z:
```

Instead use `for column, row in zip(sudlist, rows):` and you won't need to use the pos index

```
            if num not in sudlist[pos] or num not in rows[pos]:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: You're right that the OP's variable names are poorly chosen, but I don't think that "avoid single-letter names" is quite the right criterion. What names would you prefer here: `def quadratic(a, b, c): return [(-b + sign * sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a) for sign in (-1,+1)]`

Comment: @GarethRees, agreed that its not absolute, that's why I said "avoid" not "never do this"